# Loading Image from remote server

Tags: codenameone

I'm loading images in codename one apps from remote server. How to display new images when these are updated on server?

Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("xxxx");
Image icon = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "xxxx", "remote_link");

I'm loading images in codename one apps from remote server. The images take a lot of time to load and unfortunately still when the images are updated on the server, the application continues to display the old images

Answer (score 0):

The old images will display as long as the local file exists and as long as you have the image object in ram. Frankly if you don't want caching using `URLImage` might not be the best approach. You can use something like [downloadImageToStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#downloadImageToStorage-java.lang.String-com.codename1.util.SuccessCallback-) which gives you a bit more flexibility or even just a regular `Rest` request for `byte[]` data.

About speed I will need more details to give an authoritative answer. If your image on the server are large then you're effectively downloading a lot of redundant data and "paying" for it. `URLImage` hides it to some degree by scaling the image down and removing overhead after the fact but you'd still waste bandwidth. You can increase the number of network threads (defined in the `init(Object)` method usually) which might improve performance for some cases but at some point you're limited by the bandwidth you have on the device.

Comment: Thanks Sir. There is no way to clear the uploaded image object from ram or local storage?

Comment: If you no longer use the image or reference it from anywhere it will be cleared automatically. We can't explicitly "delete" the image if a reference exists to it as it will cause a memory corruption.